# MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine is null

Tags: c#, windows-services, msmq, windows-server-2012

I have a windows service and a queue on the same machine.

When I try to access the queue from a console app I get a reference to the queue.

But the windows service does not.

The service runs under the same credentials as VS2015.

I changed the service to run under local system, same problem.

This worked before, but doesn't now.

I changed my password  a couple of days ago, but i also changed the password for the service.

So this should work actually.

```
var _mq = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine("servername").
Where(qu => qu.Path == FormatName:DIRECT=OS:servername\\private$\\myqueue").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What exception is raised?

Comment: no exception, it is just null... I have also expected an exception..